# No need to set up a local server with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I see when I want write a Node.js web application on my local machine, I don't need to set-up a local server using WAMP or MAMP. What is node.js really doing behind the scenes? I am providing this code to make a simple hello world web app:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request,response){

    response.writeHead(200, {"content-type":"text/html"});
    response.write("hello world");
    response.end();

}).listen(8080);

console.log("server is running....");
```

When loading in my browser URL bar "localhost:8080" it works.

How this is working as and why don't I need a local server when working with Node.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have a local server... it's your Node.js application.

When you call `http.createServer()`, it creates an HTTP server.  When you call `.listen()` on that server, it binds to the requested port, and optionally requested address, and listens for connections.  When data comes in on those connections, it responds like any other HTTP server.

The HTTP server uses your request/response callback, firing it whenever a valid HTTP request comes in.

Comment: http.createServer() does create a server for me, it does make sense now. But when I put my website on a hosting server, do I still need to use "createServer()" method? I think no because my website is already uploaded on a remote server right ? this is really confusing sorry

Comment: @FaisalJulaidan Your node app isn't running within a web server.  Your Node.js application needs a way to communicate.  That's normally HTTP.  It is common to put a web server (like Nginx) in front of your application, but that HTTP server will still use HTTP to communicate with your application.

Comment: as far as I understand from your comment is that there are two types of servers 1.HTTP servers 2.Web servers? if yes, what's the difference !:) **sorry for having you disturbed**

Comment: @FaisalJulaidan No, there are many types of servers.  At the end of the day, your typical web server (like Nginx, Apache, etc.) speaks HTTP.  Your Node.js application speaks HTTP.  Your browser speaks HTTP.  HTTP is the common protocol between all of these.  Your browser can make requests to your application server directly.  It can also make requests to a web server.  It can make a request to a web server and your web server can proxy that request to your application server.  All of these things are possible.

Comment: A massive thank for you. you have opend a gate for me to learn new things. Final question, in my case above, creating a server is it application server or webserver when n using createServer() in Node.js

Comment: Your node application can run as a web server.  It would be more specific to say that your Node.js application has a built-in HTTP server.

Answer (score 2):

Because node comes out of the box with all the libraries you need to run a webserver, the http library that you are using is opening the 8080 port and handling the request with the function you provided

This part:

```
function(request,response){

    response.writeHead(200, {"content-type":"text/html"});
    response.write("hello world");
    response.end();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need it. Because node itself can be your webserver, just like in your example. Node is built on V8, which is chrome JavaScript engine .

Take a look a Express js module that gives you lots of features out of the box

Comment: Being based on V8 doesn't really explain *why* Node can act as a web server. That has more to do with the HTTP libraries that are built into Node.